# How can my app running on two emulators send/receive SMS DATA messages

Tags: android, sms, emulation

I have an app that runs on two phones and communicates via SMS data messages. It works. Testing with two phones is cumbersome; I would like to do further testing using two emulators.

When my app sends an SMS TEXT message, the other emulator receives and displays it.
When my app sends an SMS DATA message, which the app on the other emulator should receive and handle, it appears that either the message is not being sent, or it's not being received. (I don't know how to determine which is happening.)

Again, when my app sends SMS TEXT/DATA messages between phones, they both work. But when my app sends SMS TEXT/DATA messages between emulators, only the TEXT messages work.

Is there a way to make this work so I can test with two emulators rather than two phones?
Thank you.

Comment: I've done some more testing. It's possible that my app isn't waiting long enough for the other emulator to handle the sms data msg and reply, so it behaves as if nothing has been received. I'll do some more checking.

Comment: My app on the source phone sends a "start" DATA SMS to the target phone, which would be replied to if the app were running on the target phone. On the source phone, if 10 seconds elapse w/o a reply in the form of a DATA SMS, then a TEXT SMS is sent advising the user to start the app on the target phone. Once the app is started on the target phone, it sends the same "start" DATA SMS, which allows the app on the source phone to start normal communication. Debug on both emulators (with 60 sec  timeout) shows that both sides receive TEXT SMS, but neither side receives DATA SMS. Suggestions?